# Equality with complex numbers: missing property?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers.

Can someone explain me how 
$|a|^2 - a\overline{b} - b\overline{a} + |b|^2$ can be equal do $(a-b)^2$?

I think I'm missing some important property of complex numbers. I know that $ a\overline{b} + b\overline{a} = 2Re( a\overline{b})$ but I don't see how that can help me...

EDIT:
Yes I meant $|a-b|^2$

Comment: Did you mean $|a-b|^2$ maybe?

Comment: It can be if $\;a,b\in\Bbb R\;$ . For general complex, it is false.

Answer (score 2):

The identity 
$|a|^2 - a\overline{b} - b\overline{a} + |b|^2=(a-b)^2$ is not true in general. For instance, think about the case when
$$
a=i,\quad b=0.
$$
But $|a|^2 - a\overline{b} - b\overline{a} + |b|^2=|a-b|^2$ is ture for any $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $|a-b|^2 = (a-b) \overline{(a-b)} = (a-b)(\bar a - \bar b) = \;...$

Note that in general $|a-b|^2 \ne (a-b)^2$ unless it happens that $a-b \in \mathbb{R}$.